# Ant stopped working in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, configuration

My `Ant` was working fine till today, today I installed `TestNG` plugin and after restart `Ant` is not there.
I cant see option in Eclipse Preferences and I cant see `Ant` view also.

I also tried to install the latest `Ant-Ivy` plugin but no luck.

Can anyone help me?

I am using Eclipse Mars & JDK 1.7.

[image: Eclipse View, where build file is shown as normal xml file]

I was able to run the build file from external ANT but not from Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Check your preferences :
`General | Editors | File Associations`

`Ant | Runtime`
Maybe your problems are related to that [eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=470390) !?
The [workaround using a symbolic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31177810/130683) link works fine.

Comment: What I need to check in File Association? Also as said in question, Ant is not visible in Preferences.

Comment: @Garry File Association because " .. where build file is shown as normal XML file" so it seemed to me it's not associated with ant editor. NO ant preferences anymore ?, ok didn't get that from your question. Has ErrorLog view any helpful entries ?

Comment: Lots of errors...."org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Widget has the wrong parent)"....Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/icons/full/eview16/source.gif"

Comment: @Garry are there any entries for the eclipse ant plugin => org.eclipse.ant... ? Test if ant reappears afters uninstalling Testng plugin, if yes you may open an issue here => https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I was able to run the build file from external ANT but not from Eclipse.