# Eclipse Mars: ANT Task references missing SWT library

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I just upgraded to Eclipse Mars and suddenly my ANT task working fine with Lunar complains:

```
The archive: C:/Program%20Files/eclipse_lunar/plugins/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_3.104.0.v20150528-0211.jar which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist.
```

Which is weird, because

- I'm sure none .classpath file does reference to this jar
- the jar actually exists under that path

After some research it seems it is related to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=470390

Anyone has a solution to run my ANT (besides from using lunar again) ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
mklink /D D:\Program%20Files "D:\Program Files"
```

Comment: Some idea as mine but I like the link better :)

Answer (score 4):

Move the eclipse program directory to **another folder wihtout spaces**

- for example simply to `c:\eclipse`

Comment: If you do this, you'll also have to update your Ant Home setting in Window->Preferences->Ant->Runtime.

Answer (score 4):

**Problem:**

Error message:

> The archive:
>   C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Eclipse%20Mars/plugins/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_3.104.0.v20150528-0211.jar
>   which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist.

The problem was the Eclipse Mars is downloaded and extracted under a folder which space contained in its name. In the above error message the path contains folder names with spaces in between and displayed as `%20`.

**Solution:**

Inorder to solve this use anyone of the workaround mentioned below,

- Remove any spaces in any of the directory where you have stored Eclipse.
  eg: Rename `My Folder` to `MyFolder`
- Move you eclipse to the root of any drive(C: or D: or F: etc)
  eg: `D:\eclipse-jee-mars-R-win32-x86_64`
- Create a symbolic link folder in windows using mklink command,

  `mklink /d D:\My%20Folder "D:\My Folder"`

You'll get the following message,

`symbolic link created for D:\My%20Folder <<===>> D:\My Folder`

*Note: For creating symbolic link you need to run the above command in the elevated command prompt.*

Now you can run the ant scripts without the above error. This is a bug reported to eclipse and will be patched in the future releases.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to create the folder
"C:\Program%20Files\eclipse_lunar\plugins" and place a copy of the actual *.jar from "C:\Program Files\eclipse_lunar\plugins" there

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this, as it could potentially cause inexplicable behavior from other programs further down the line. A contrived example is to try to cd into that folder in a batch script.